# NullPointerException when try to write result to excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver

Can someone help with this code?
I receive an error message about NullPointerException at 41 row. I know that it returns null but this value is required for following verification. The general task is to write result to excel file.

```
 public class ExcelUtils {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            //Blank workbook
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

            //Create a blank sheet
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee Data");

            String Result = "TEST TEST TEST";
            int RowNum = 2;
            int ColNum = 3;
            XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet = sheet;
            XSSFCell Cell;
            XSSFRow Row;

            try
                {


                    Row  = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum);

                    Cell = Row.getCell(ColNum, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

                    if (Cell == null) {

                        Cell = Row.createCell(ColNum);

                        Cell.setCellValue(Result);

                        } else {

                            Cell.setCellValue(Result);

                        }




                //---------------------------------------------------


                    //try
                   // {
                    //Write the workbook in file system
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx"));
                    workbook.write(out);
                    out.close();
                    System.out.println("howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }


    }
```

Comment: Row 41 is a comment in the code you posted. Could you specify the exact line?

Comment: `ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum);` returns null. You forgot to create the row.

Comment: @Jokab Cell = Row.getCell(ColNum, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL); this row

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Cell = Row.getCell(ColNum, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL); this row

Comment: @Jack Read my comment again. You're getting a NPE on the line you're pointing out because the `Row` returned on the previous line is `null`.

Comment: @Jack I cannot understand ur requirement clearly.Do you wish to write data in String result to cell(2,3) is that ur only requirement or do you wish to check if value already exists ie)if it is not null then write otherwise dont write the result to the cell(2,3) or did i totally misunderstood ur question

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Oh, yes it works. Thank you very much !

Comment: @Vicky The requirements there are, you need to check if the cell is blank to write to the result if not then just set value.

Comment: I want to shift information about cells and result in function that will record the data in Excel

Comment: Hi @Jack If you want to write data to the excel file only when the cell is empty then u should first read the excel file otherwise how do you know whether the cell is empty currently the above code will write "TEST TEST TEST" in the cell(2,3) even if the cell already contains the value ie)even if it is not empty

Comment: But I can write result in one cell only

Comment: Hi @Vicky can you tell me how to make a function for writing data in Excel file?

Comment: @Jack I Have added the function.Kindly chk and get back if you need any changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the Result string from your test method to the method writeexcel.You don't need to create an object as the method is static

```
writeexcel("pass",2,3);
```

This will call the writeexcel method and will write the string passed as an argument ie) "pass" in the respective cell

**Method** :

```
public static void writeexcel(String Result,int RowNum ,int ColNum)
    {
        //Blank workbook
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

        //Create a blank sheet
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee Data");
        XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet = sheet;
        XSSFCell Cell;
        XSSFRow Row;

        try
            {


                Row  = ExcelWSheet.createRow(RowNum);

                Cell = Row.getCell(ColNum, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

                if (Cell == null) {

                    Cell = Row.createCell(ColNum);

                    Cell.setCellValue(Result);

                    } else {

                        Cell.setCellValue(Result);

                    }

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx"));
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
                System.out.println("howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

**EDIT**

```
public class Tests {

    static XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    static  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee Data");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int j=3;

    for(int i=2;i<=5;i++) { 

        String result = "Test "+i;

        writeexcel(result, i, j);

    }
    writetoexcel();//write to cell(2,3),(3,3),(4,3)
    }

    public static void writeexcel(String Result,int RowNum ,int ColNum)
    {

        //Create a blank sheet

        XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet = sheet;
        XSSFCell Cell;
        XSSFRow Row;

        try
            {
                Row  = ExcelWSheet.createRow(RowNum);

                Cell = Row.getCell(ColNum, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

                if (Cell == null) {

                    Cell = Row.createCell(ColNum);

                    Cell.setCellValue(Result);

                    } else {

                        Cell.setCellValue(Result);

                    }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public static void writetoexcel(){

        try{
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
    }
```

Hope this helps you...Kindly get back if you need any further help

Comment: Yes, it works but I can't use this function dynamically. There is part of my code where I am used my function `for (i=0;i<=5;i++) { 
        driver.findElement(By.className("noClass")).click();
        result = driver.getCurrentUrl().toString();
        ExcelUtils.write(result, i, j);
        i++; j++;
        System.out.println("Before: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        driver.navigate().back();
        result = driver.getCurrentUrl().toString();
        ExcelUtils.write(result, i, j);
        System.out.println("After: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        i++;  j++;}`

Comment: When using this function to fill file, data is rewrote

Comment: @Jack what is i and j  are they RowNum and ColNum.Do you mean u want to pass rownum and column num dynamically??

Comment: i and j is row and column number. Yes I want to pass data in each cell .

Comment: I try any variants but in all cases the file is rewrote data

Comment: @Jack it is occuring since you're creating file multiple times...you need to change ur code i have tweaked ur code and posted an working example.Kindly refer the above edit

Answer (score 0):

```
static String sheetname = "TEST";

static XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

static  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetname);



public static void writeexcel(String Result,int RowNum ,int ColNum)
{

    //Create a blank sheet

    XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet = sheet;
    XSSFCell Cell;
    XSSFRow Row;

    try
        {
            Row  = ExcelWSheet.createRow(RowNum);

            Cell = Row.getCell(ColNum, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

            if (Cell == null) {

                Cell = Row.createCell(ColNum);

                Cell.setCellValue(Result);

                } else {

                    Cell.setCellValue(Result);

                }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public static void writetoexcel(String namefile) throws IOException{

    String namefile1 = namefile+".xlsx";

    if(namefile1.equals(namefile1)){

        try {
            // Open the Excel file

            FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(namefile1);

            // Access the required test data sheet

            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);

            sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetname);
            System.out.println("This file is already exist. The system is opened this file for adding information");


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    } else {

    try{
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(namefile1));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Hi @Vicky I try this method but in this case data is not added to file

Comment: Who know how to write data in a few columns and rows