# Getting null pointer exception while trying to write in xlsx file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, xlsx

I am getting following error while writing values to last column of the row.
The last cell has to be created new.

`java.lang.NullPointerException     at com.dnb.util.WriteExcel.writeXLSXFile(WriteExcel.java:37)    at com.dnb.reducer.ComparisionReducer.reduce(ComparisionReducer.java:47)    at com.dnb.reducer.ComparisionReducer.reduce(ComparisionReducer.java:1)     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:566)   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:408)     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:216)`

My Code is

```
public class WriteExcel {

    public void writeXLSXFile(int row, String value) throws IOException {
        try {
             FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\582092\\Desktop\\Inputs\\Book2.xlsx"));
             XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
             XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
             Row r = sheet.getRow(row);
             int col = sheet.getRow(row).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
             Cell cell = r.createCell(col);
             cell.setCellValue(value);
             file.close();
             FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\582092\\Desktop\\Inputs\\Book1.xlsx"));
             workbook.write(outFile);
             outFile.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

My Question is i have a excel file with 12 columns.
I am going to do some validation with this 12 columns and i want to write the result of this validation in 13th column of each row.

When i try to do this I am getting NullPointer Exception.

Actually I am getting this error in this line

> cell.setCellValue(value);

Comment: do you know what is FileNotFound exception?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783908/nullpointerexception-when-try-to-write-result-to-excel

Comment: @AshishSrivastava I tried the link you gave already. But that didn't help me.

Comment: Maybe you should check `if (cell != null) { cell.setCellValue(value); ...`

Comment: @Gowtham Actually there many more such links here. You can browse many related post.

Comment: Thanks @AshishSrivastava. I will check on that or i will go with some other way.

Comment: @cricket_007 i have tried that too. It didn't work.